# Can image.present? replace both !image.nil? and !image.blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Instead of using:

```
!image.nil? and !image.blank?
```

Can I use *image.present?* to replace both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`present?` [definition is](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F):

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 22
def present?
  !blank?
end
```

and `blank?` [definition is](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F):

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb, line 15
def blank?
  respond_to?(:empty?) ? !!empty? : !self 
end
```

So:

- `!image.nil? and !image.blank?` could just be: `!image.blank?`
- `!image.blank?` is `image.present?`

as a result `!image.nil? and !image.blank?` is the same as `image.present?`

Answer (score 0):

yes.. it's also useful in checking empty arrays:

```
[].present?  == false
```